# What happens in the case of a Postgres Transaction Rollback command not reaching the database?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

Section 3.4 of the Postgres documentation covers transactions.

I thought a transaction worked according to the following rules:

1. The client sends a BEGIN statement to the Database server on a connection. Call this connection “connection_one”.
2. The client sends whatever queries they want to the Database server. All of these queries are sent via “connection_one”.
3. If at any time the connection (in this example “connection_one”) is lost before a COMMIT statement reaches the Database server, the Database server rollsback to before the BEGIN statement.
4. If a COMMIT statement is issued and received by the Database server, then the changes are saved and then transaction block has completed.

It looks like the above is not the case though. My confusion is that it looks like I have to actually issue a ROLLBACK command and have it reach the Database Server in order for partial changes not to be saved. Is this really the case or am I missing something? If it is the case is there any way I can get the above behavior to occur or is there some reason I would not want the above behavior to occur? My concern is what if the connection is lost before I am able to ROLLBACK.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldnt see any changes until the `COMMIT` occur

Comment: When you say "It looks like the above is not the case though", can you explain what you're seeing that makes things look different than you expect? As Juan Carlos said, the behavior you describe in 1-4 is correct and expected. If you're seeing something else, we need to know what you're seeing in order to be able to help you.